# Get userId on database in Silex Project

Tags: php, symfony, silex

I started a new project with Silex, it looks like a cool and fast Framework but I'm getting crazy with the SecurityServiceProvider trying to get the uid. I though it should be something like the getId() like Symfony but I got an error that the function doesn't exists.

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorage::getUser()

If I got the current logged user I have his information but not the Id.

```
$user = $app['user'];
print_r($user);
```

> Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User Object (
>   [username:Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User:private] =>
>   myuser@mymail.com
>   [password:Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User:private] =>
>   5FZ2Z8QIkA7UTZ4BYkoC+GsReLf569mSKDsfods6LYQ8t+a8EW9oaircfMpmaLbPBh4FOBiiFyLfuZmTSUwzZg==
>   [enabled:Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User:private] => 1
>   [accountNonExpired:Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User:private]
>   => 1 [credentialsNonExpired:Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User:private]
>   => 1 [accountNonLocked:Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User:private]
>   => 1 [roles:Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User:private] => Array ( [0] => ROLE_USER ) )

Any idea? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
// Symfony 2.6+
$token = $app['security.token_storage']->getToken();

// Symfony 2.3/2.5
$token = $app['security']->getToken();
```

Get user info:

```
$user = $token->getUser();
```

Check `$user`

```
var_dump($user);
```

Comment: I did that, and got the same

Comment: You already installed composer require symfony/security right ? and registered to your $app ?

Comment: Of course, if not, I couldn't do the login process.

Comment: I'm using a custom Provider, maybe I need to specify all the fields I want to take from the users table, but really don't know where :/

Comment: If you can send github or etc. link i can check it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok got the solution, if anybody implements a new UserProvider, should to add the customs fields on the provider, and define them on User class in Symfony. Thanks anyway!